# Definition of trace in Bourbaki

Tags: definition, trace, filters

Bourbaki, General Topology, p. 61 (1966)

What is the definition of **trace** in the following Proposition?

**Proposition 8.** Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a filter on a set $X$ and $A$ a subset of $X$. Then the trace $\mathcal{F}_A$ of $\mathcal{F}$ on $A$ is a filter if and only if each set of $\mathcal{F}$ meets $A$.

My guess:

> **Definition.** Given a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ and a subset $x\subseteq X$, the **trace** of $\mathcal{F}$ on $x$ is denoted and defined by
>   $$
> \mathcal{F}_x:=\{x\cap y:y\in\mathcal{F}\}.
> $$

I have not found the definition in the book, in any case there is no trace of the trace in the index.

Possibly this definition is fallen into disuse, because some online search gave me no result.

Comment: Having checked in the original (French) version,  it is defined in the *Set theory* book.

Comment: @Bernard. Thank you. Which is the given definition? The one I guessed?

Comment: @Bernard Where does it appear?  It seems that [*Topologie générale*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=12yuCBbwijUC&pg=SA1-PA40#v=onepage&q&f=false) is more relevant.  See the "Définition 5" immediately after the "Proposition 8".  It's actually a "proposition-definition".

Comment: @PeptideChain: Yes exactly. If you want a reference, it is the last item (n° 16) the *Fascicule de Résultats*, §1 (not sure whether it has been translated into English – it means something like *Results Booklet*).

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: I don't agree – it's a very general (and informal) notion, which is not linked to topology.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for reminding me.  Btw, when you need to notify the post owner, you _don't_ need to tag him/her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition that you're after is taken from Bourbaki's *Theory of Sets* (chapter II, section 4, subsection 5):

> The intersection $X\cap A$ is sometimes called the *trace* of $X$ on $A$. If $\mathcal F$ is a family of sets, the set of traces on $A$ of the sets belonging to $\mathcal F$ is called the *trace* of $\mathcal F$ on $A$.